# Is it ok to create an object before Application.Initialize?

Tags: delphi

Is it ok to create an object (my own class) before Application.Initialize?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it ok to create an object (my own class) before Application.Initialize?

Certainly. You can do anything you like in your program (*.dpr file).

In fact, you may have been doing this already, without knowing it. If you have ever used the `initialization` section of a unit -- or a modern `class constructor` -- you have executed your own code prior to `Application.Initialize`.

Writing custom code at this early time of your program's lifetime is neither unusual nor bad practice.

But you should be extra careful, of course, because the pre-`Application.Run` environment is subtly different from the `Application.Run` environment. For instance, an unhandled exception will kill your app.

Comment: "initialization section" - You are right. I never thought about it like that :)